# online video playing issues

Tags: video, graphics-card

for some unknown reasons when I play an online video on youtube or Facebook, the area where the video plays got damaged:
[image: Example]

Gif example: gifyu.com/image/Bpnh
Sometimes this damage running for just a 5 sec or 10 or maybe in some parts.
The problem is not from the source because I try to open the same videos on another machine and there was no problem.

Can anyone tell me how to fix that or what's the problem?!

Comment: Is the screenshot show showing the complete screen or just the area where the video plays?

Comment: just the area where the video plays

Comment: Then it is most likely an incompatibility of the used video hardware decoder and the video. Update your drivers for the graphic card. Or it is a hardware defect of the graphic card.

Comment: already updated the drivers for the graphic card, but when I download the same video, it works locally, the problem only when playing online videos

Comment: here is example : https://gifyu.com/image/Bpnh

Comment: If you download a video from Youtube then it can be different from the one you directly play (e.g. different codec).

Comment: so strange because I have 2 GPUs, intel uhd graphics 630 and Nvidia gtx1050 :/

Comment: What is the player program? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: @harrymc this is facebook website opened from chrome brower

Comment: Try in Chrome to flip the setting for "Use hardware acceleration when available" that is found in *Settings >  Advanced > System*.

Comment: @harrymc found it enabled, after disabling it and relanche, wow the problem disappeared, thanks, but why this happens, is it from chrome or from my GPU ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by disabling in Chrome the option of
"Use hardware acceleration when available".
This is found in *Settings >  Advanced > System*.

This is a common problem with Chrome, for which no clear explanation
was ever given.

It's possible that Chrome has a bug with using some GPUs.
It's equally possible that Chrome is wrongly analyzing the type
of the GPU and is trying to drive the wrong one.

Whatever the explanation, at least the solution is known:
To disable Chrome from using the GPU.